# IOS7,8,9 receive previous push notification behavior

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to develop an app to receive push notifications with a user account.

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
```

Once the registration successfully, the deviceToken is linked to a user account.

There is a scenario when the `userA` completes registration and uninstalls the app, the app ideally will not receive the push notification from APNs, but another userB installs it without registration, with the same iPhone, the iPhone will receive the `userA`'s push notification because the deviceToken is the same as previous.

In fact, the `userB` should not receive the `userA`'s push notification with the same device. Luckily, it only exists in IOS7,8 but not in iOS9 (iOS9 is disabled the push permission until the user grant the permission)

How to solve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of handling this issue is:

1 ) As soon as user login to device do **unregister your device for remote notification** .This way, it will ensure that next set of notification won't reach to device even if application server sends it to device.

Sample code for how to unregister (see logout method):

https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK/blob/af7b6b1e9ebeb2d7a7679a887e5d3a17b1b6b4ca/sample-with-framework/Applozic/Applozic/Services/ALRegisterUserClientService.m

2) Register your device for remote notification again and send the new token to application server. For extra check application server will do following.

i) Check for the device token sent to application server, if same is linked with any other user (lets say userA )reset that token.

ii) Store device token and linked with the current user(Say userB ).

Hope this will help.

Comment: So according to it, Previous registrations will be nullified if ANY on login !

Comment: I understand the 1 & 2 solutions by @Adarsh, but one more scenario, once the UserB doesn't launch the app, then the deviceToken would not update on the application server. So the APNs will push the UserA's notification to the UserB's device. if the UserB doesn't launch the app, how can I remove the deviceToken in the server? does the APNs reply any callback to the server to let me know the app is removed/ reinstalled?